# How can I make an object move in a certain direction depending on its spawning point?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm currently developing a 2D game and I couldn't find a way to figure this out. In the game, I have 4 different balls and 4 different spawning points. Every 2 seconds, a random ball spawns at a random spawning point.
[image: Ball Movement]
What I want to achieve is, as I tried to describe above, lets say a ball spawns on right side, I want it to move towards left, if it spawns upside, I want it to go downwards etc.

Here is my spawner code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public GameObject[] balls;

    public float timer = 2.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        SpawnBalls ();
    }
    void SpawnBalls()
    {
        int spawnPoints_num = Random.Range (0, 4);
        int balls_num = Random.Range (0, 4);

        if (timer <= 0)
        {
        Instantiate (balls [balls_num], spawnPoints [spawnPoints_num].position, spawnPoints [spawnPoints_num].rotation);
        timer = 2.0f;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my ball movement code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Balls : MonoBehaviour {

    public Game game;
    public float speed = 0.25f;

    void Start () 
    {
        game = FindObjectOfType<Game> ();
    }

    void Update () 
    {
    //Some if statement
    //transform.Translate (Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    //else if
    //transform.Translate (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    //else if
    //transform.Translate (Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    //else if
    //transform.Translate (Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

I've tried giving spawnpoints tags and creating if statements with gameObject.tag and stuff but couldn't find a way to work it. How can I make it check which spawnpoint the ball spawned at so I can make it move accordingly?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can't you just compare their spawn position with the center and make them move depending upon it?.

Comment: I guess I could do that but it feels like it's the long way to do it. I would want to learn the proper way so to speak. But that gave me an idea, maybe I can do something like if the spawnpoints' x or y value is greater or lower than a  certain value, I can give Speed or -speed on x/y axis depending on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, even though I couldn't manage to learn what I wanted, I figured a way out.

```
Instantiate (balls [balls_num], spawnPoints [spawnPoints_num].position,spawnPoints [spawnPoints_num].rotation, spawnPoints [spawnPoints_num]);
```

I added spawnPoints [spawnPoints_num] at the end of instantiate which makes the ball, children of the spawnpoint it got spawned at. After that I just gave spawnpoints tags and did a simple transform.parent.tag check, and go from there. Thanks everyone for their input.

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference to the spawn point. Orient its forward axis(the blue one) in the direction you want your spawned object to move and use this :

```
 transform.Translate(spawnPoint.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

Comment: This accomplished what I wanted but now I have a different problem. When I use: spawnPoints [spawnPoints_num].rotation on Instantiate, it moves as ı wanted but I'm unable to see the sprites, and if I use balls [balls_num].transform.rotation/localrotation, I see the sprites but they move in the wrong axis.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is the Vector3.MoveTowards method. try the following

```
    public Transform target;
    public float speed;
    void Update()
    {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
```

Comment: I know how to do it by creating a game object and move the ball towards that. What I'm looking for is as I described, I'm looking for a way to make it detect and assign a ball to its spawn point so I can make it move towards where I want depending on the spawn point.

Comment: what is the difference between each ball in the array of balls you created

Comment: I don't think MoveTowards is the right approach unless you have a specific target point. The asker wants to move it in a fixed direction, and that can and should be done without an artificial target object somewhere.

Comment: @IdoBenShalom Nothing, just the colors